# PHP Sorting of Database Results

Tags: php, database, sorting

I'm building a Database retrieval using PHP and I want to be able to sort the results based on their different classifications.

By default, the posts should be ordered most recently created to oldest.  For now I'm just trying to have the others sort A-Z in ascending order, but would like to do both A-Z ascending and descending.

```
<?php

// Determine the sort...
// Default is by registration date.
$sort = (isset($_GET['sort'])) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'sort_date';

// Determine the sorting order:
switch ($sort) {
    case 'sort_neighborhood':
        $order_by = 'Neighborhood ASC';
        break;
    case 'sort_method':
        $order_by = 'Method ASC';
        break;
    case 'sort_category':
        $order_by = 'Category ASC';
        break;
    case 'sort_price':
        $order_by = 'Price ASC';
        break;
    case 'sort_condition':
        $order_by = 'Condit ASC';
        break;
    case 'sort_date':
        $order_by = 'Date ASC';
        break;
    default:
        $order_by = 'Date DESC';
        $sort = 'sort_date';
        break;
}

// Connects to your Database
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'password', 'Listings') OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

$q = "SELECT Name, Email, Neighborhood, Method, Title, Category, Description, Price, Condit, Photo, Date FROM Listings"; 
$r = @mysqli_query ($con, $q); //Run the query.
// Count the number of returned rows:
$num = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if ($num > 0) {

    // Print
    echo '<table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><a href="Retrieve.php?sort=sort_neighborhood">Neighborhood</a></td>
                <td><a href="Retrieve.php?sort=sort_method">Method</a></td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td><a href="Retrieve.php?sort=sort_category">Category</a></td>
                <td>Description</td>
                <td><a href="Retrieve.php?sort=sort_price">Price</a></td>
                <td><a href="Retrieve.php?sort=sort_condition">Condition</a></td>
                <td>Photo</td>
                <td><a href="Retrieve.php?sort=sort_date">Date</a></td>
            </tr>';
    // Fetch and print all the records:
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        $split = explode("/home/xyz/public_html", $row['Photo']);
        $base = $split['0'];
        $src = $split['1'];

        echo '<tr>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Name'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Email'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Neighborhood'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Method'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Title'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Category'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Description'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Price'] . '</td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Condit'] . '</td>
            <td align="left"><img src=" ' . $src . '"></td>
            <td align="left">' . $row['Date'] . '</td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }
    echo '</table>';
                mysqli_free_result ($r);    
    } else { // If no records were returned.
    echo '<p class="error">There are currently no posts.</p>';
    }

mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: you'd need two parameters, then: one for the field to be sorted, and another one for the direction. e.g `example.com/script.php&field=condit&direction=desc`

Comment: @MarcB am I missing something? he can just add order by '$order_by' to the query... He has this string already

Comment: @michael: "but would like to do both ascending descending". either you have two parameters, or you double up the number of choices so you have `foo asc` and `foo desc`. either way, you're doubling up SOMETHING.

Comment: @MarcB your reputation makes me think you're right... :-) But the switch he wrote only has the option for ASC in it, so I thought he wants to sort the date DESC and ASC (like in the switch and rest of code) and the rest only ASC. Hm, what will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to this query:

```
$q = "SELECT Name, Email, Neighborhood, Method, Title, Category, Description, Price, Condit, Photo, Date FROM Listings";
```

this:

```
ORDER BY '$order_by'
```

after FROM LISTINGS

Answer (score -1):

all you have to do is to concatenate `$order_by` with `$q`

```
$q.="ORDER BY ";
$q.=$order_by;
```

and your `mysql` command will be like this

```
mysqli_query=($con,$q)
```